# Return List from ROS subscriber

Tags: python, ros

I have a ROS subscriber that passes data into a callback function, which then prints out all passed-on data. I would like to append all values that are printed out into a list, and to use that list outside of ROS.

I first thought about appending all data to the list in the callback function, and return the list. But when I tried to call and print the subscriber, which would not give me the list I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

ROS callbacks do not return anything so you cannot rely on a `return` statement. The way this should be done is via setting a class attribute list. Take the following for example:

```
class mock_class:
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('my_node')
        self.my_list = []
        rospy.Subscriber('/some_topic', String, self.my_cb)

    def my_cb(self, msg):
        self.my_list.append(msg.data)

    def get_data(self):
        return self.my_list
```

Here every time the callback is called it will append the current data to a list that's stored as a class attribute. This keeps the data persistent and able to be retrieved at a later time.